# Inserting a row to a table with auto_increment column

Tags: php, mysql, insert, mysqli, auto-increment

I'm working on a table that has 4 columns and the first one is an auto incrementing integer called id.

If I'm going to insert into this table using mysqli prepared statements I keep having trouble inserting a query that works. Using phpMyAdmin It tells me to give it NULL. I've tried this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl (id, col2, col3, col4) VALUES ('NULL', ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt -> bind_param("ssi", $col2, $col3, $col4)
```

And this

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl (id, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt -> bind_param("ssi", $col2, $col3, $col4)
```

And only give bind_param 3 arguments (the last 3). Neither of those work. I also tried this:

```
$null = NULL;
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl (id, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt -> bind_param("issi", $null, $col2, $col3, $col4);
```

None of these work. Is there a standardized way of inserting into this type of table?

Comment: do u also want to insert auto-incremtn field explicitly?

Comment: "Keep having trouble" sounds like you should start checking for error messages. They might help you to find the error more easily than just fiddling around until it works

Answer (score 18):

Just skip the `id` field, MySQL will fill it automatically:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl (col2, col3, col4) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $col2, $col3, $col4)
```

Answer (score 7):

If the `id` field is the `auto_increment`, then just don't specify it in your `insert` query :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl (col2, col3, col4) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
```

And, of course, don't try to bind any parameter to it ;-)

As it's generated by MySQL, there is no need to pass that column.

Answer (score 5):

This should work, because id is added automatically (incremented for this reason) by mysql:

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO tbl (col2, col3, col4) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
```

In some cases, you have to insert auto_incremtnt field explicitly, if this is the case then you can use the `INSERT IGNORE` statement, see mysql manual for more info about it.

Answer (score 3):

This one

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl (id, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt -> bind_param("ssi", $col2, $col3, $col4)
```

should surely work. What is the exact error you get?

Now I look better, you have $query and $stmt. What do you have in between? Probably you are missing some part.

It should be

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl (id, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt -> bind_param("ssi", $col2, $col3, $col4);
$stmt ->execute();
```